# Can't get desktop page to display reliably on mobile

Tags: mobile

I'm working on a page [here](http://zackel.com/165/index.html)   that I can't get to display sanely on a mobile phone. I'm reading it with a Samsung S7.  The page looks like this on the desktop (without the width arrow and dimension):

[image]

and that's what I would like to see on the S7: a simple scaled down version of the original.  The width is 1200px.   I have the meta viewport tag below on the page:

```
<meta name="viewport"  content="width=1200, initial-scale=3">
```

Sometimes this viewport tag works, giving me exactly what I want.  But if I load it again, the page may load offset to the left so that the menu is off screen.  Or it will load magnified.  After it loaded incorrectly once, I kept tapping and swiping and it suddenly snapped to the correct layout above.

I've experimented with the viewport tag.  The initial-scale value doesn't seem to have an affect,  I've tried 1 and 3 it's worked with both and failed with both. The width seems to have to be 1200 or it will fail everytime.

Can anyone suggest why this is behaving so erratically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> a simple scaled down version of the original.

For that, you should not use

```
<meta name="viewport"  content="width=1200, initial-scale=3">
```

Use

```
<meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Because, if you set `width=1200px`, you may have to scroll it in mobile device.

But in `width=device-width`, it automatically fetch the available width of device and stretch accordingly.

You can read the official documentation here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

There are some other attributes regarding to zooming.

They are `minimum-scale` , `maximum-scale`, `user-scalable`.

`minimum-scale` -> The minimum zoom level `<int>` value

`maximum-scale` -> The maximum zoom level `<int>` value

`user-scalable` -> Whether allow the user to zoom or not. `yes` or `no`

Comment: Thanks.  I put in <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> and the first few times it seemed to work, showing the full page with the menu on the left. But then I played with the other attributes (minimum-scale, etc.), got nowhere, went back to the above tag, and then it didn't work anymore either.It's in now and for me the page always loads at 2X and nothing will let me see the whole page with the menu on the left. I put "view-source:" in front of the url to load the source and I can see that right tag is definitely loaded.  ???

Comment: It is because of caching. Try clear the cache and load the site. @Steve

Comment: I think I did that: three dots > Settings > Advanced, etc. Is there a better way to clear a mobile (S7 for me) cache?  Are you getting the full page when you load it?

Comment: I got this from the link you provided, while inspected `<meta name="viewport"  content="width=1200, initial-scale=3">` So, I think you missed something or rollbacked to a earlier version.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I just changed the link in the question to point where I put  the new tag..

Comment: Since it is worked for you before changing again, you may missed something in the rollback. Try setting initial scale with `1.0` instead of `1`
that is `<meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`